# Karate expression to check if value exists in array

Tags: karate

Here is my sample feature file:

```
Feature: Karate expression to check if status within array of status.

  Scenario: Test
    * def status = "ACTIVE"
    * def possibleStatus = ["ACTIVE", "INACTIVE"]
    * match status contains possibleStatus ?
```

Is there a way to check if status is either ACTIVE or INACTIVE using karate expression ?

**NOTE:** It can definitely be achieved by writing custome JS function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy one.

```
* def status = "ACTIVE"
* def possibleStatus = ["ACTIVE", "INACTIVE"]
* match possibleStatus contains status
```

Any questions :)

Comment: is it possible to check same as part of schema validation ? 
  
`def schema =
    """
    {
      status: ?
    }
    """
  `
   match each response.data contains schema

Comment: @DJ342 not clear. ask a new question and provide a proper example please

Comment: Sure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103176/schema-validation-karate-expression-to-check-if-value-exists-in-array